# Eloquent Javascript - correlation and coefficient

Tags: correlation, binary-data, javascript

Currently I'm reading **Eloquent Javascript** book and at **chapter 4**. This topic entitled '**The lycanthrope’s log** ' is very confusing to me. How important is **correlation** and **coefficient** in real world programming?

I'm trying to understand the formula used to find correlation. I've far forgotten maths since I left my high school. Could, someone who've read this book, **explain to me in detail**, please? Below is the picture I'm wondering about..

[image]

Comment: When you say "correlation *and* coefficient", you appear to be talking about two things -- what coefficient do you mean, besides the correlation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula is actually pretty straight forward. Consider the table from your question.

> The table states that there were a total **90 observations**

Out of all 90 observations:

1. **76 times**, no pizzas or squirrel
2. **9 times**, pizzas but no squirrel
3. **4 times**, squirrel but no pizzas
4. **1 time**, both squirrel and pizza

> So we want to find out how **Pizzas** & **Squirrels** are related:

---

Consider the equation along with your table now,

(since squirrel is on the left)

#### n00 denotes an observation where there was **no squirrel or pizza** (1)

#### n01 denotes an observation where there was **no squirrel but pizza** (2)

#### n10 denotes an observation where there was **squirrel but no pizza** (3)

#### n11 denotes an observation where there was **both squirrel but pizza** (4)

---

#### n0. refers to the sum of all measurements where we have **no squirrel**

#### n.0 refers to the sum of all measurements where we have **no pizza**

#### n1. refers to the sum of all measurements where we have **squirrel**

#### n.1 refers to the sum of all measurements where we have **pizza**

---

*Now that we know what these values are, let's plug them in to our formula*:

$$    \mathit{correlation} = \rho = \frac{ 1 \times 76 - 4 \times 9}{\sqrt{5 \times 85 \times 10 \times 80}}$$

Comment: Well, tbh I had to research the thing first :P

Comment: It might be worth noting that if you code the binary variables for "no-squirrel/squirrel" and "no-pizza/pizza" as (0,1) (or indeed any other two distinct values where the "no" part is either lower for both or higher for both) then this is actually the same as the ordinary correlation coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late since this question was asked 5 years, 9 months ago. But I hope my explanation will help you to understand the phi coefficient in this book better. Things we know from this book are:

- **The first variable** is the squirrel.
- **the second variable** is the pizza.
- If the variable is false it is 0.
- If the variable is true it is 1.

Based on that we can compile the first line of the phi coefficient's formula:

1. **n11** both of the variables are true (both squirrel and pizza are true): the value is 1.
2. **n00** both of the variables are false (both squirrel and pizza are false): the value is 76.
3. **n10** the first variable/squirrel is true but the pizza is false: the value is 4.
4. **n01** the first variable is false and the second is true: 9.

So, for the second line (√ n1• x n0• x n•1 x n•0), we need to see where the number and the dot (.) are located. If the dot is after the number, then we are talking about the first value which is a squirrel with 0 or 1 indicating the true or false. And vice versa. For example:

1. **n1.** : the dot is after a number so we are talking about the first variable which is a squirrel and 1 is true, so we need to sum everything where the squirrel is true (4 + 1)
2. **n0.** : the squirrel is false (76 + 9)
3. **n.1** : the dot is before the number so we are talking about the second variable which is pizza and 1 is true, so we need to sum everything where the pizza is true (9 + 1)
4. **n.0** : the pizza is false (76 + 4)

I hope my explanation will help anyone in the future who stumbles upon this problem and grasp the concept as easy as possible. Cheers!